# Cloning a Form in jQuery and Increasing the Index

Tags: jquery, forms, cloneable

This seems relatively simple, I'm just stumped on jQuery syntax.

Basically I want to take this form :

```
<div class="me_signup">
  <input type="text" name="referral[0][name]" id="referral_0_name">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="referral[0][email]" id="referral_0_email">
</div>
```

And duplicate it with a button and increase the variable number..

```
$(".add_another_button").click(function(){
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/bMhwC/1/)?

```
$(".add_another_button").click(function() {
    var $newdiv = $(".me_signup:last").clone(true);
    $newdiv.find('input').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('id', $this.attr('id').replace(/_(\d+)_/, function($0, $1) {
            return '_' + (+$1 + 1) + '_';
        }));
        $this.attr('name', $this.attr('name').replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function($0, $1) {
            return '[' + (+$1 + 1) + ']';
        }));
        $this.val('');
    });
    $newdiv.insertAfter('.me_signup:last');
});
```

Comment: YOU ARE GENIUS STATUS. Where is the golden version of you so that I can make proper obeisances?

Comment: i know i already checked this off, but i'm still blown away. I can't thank you enough. Your understanding of regex is amazingly on point.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all that html in a variable, and use .append() method to add this to a particular DOM element. And, should you clone this, be sure to change "id" to "class", because id must be unique on each page.
[Some more about .append() in official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/)